# Why cannot I mock function from module getting auth token error?

Tags: python, celery, pytest

**This is my folder structure**

```
src/celery/__init__.py (empty)

src/celery/utils.py 

scripts/__init.py (empty)

scripts/keep_alive.py  

tests/scripts/test_keep_alive.py
```

**contents of `utils.py` content**

```py
def get_auth_token():
    print("getting auth token")

    oauth_conf = get_oauth_config(celery_app_conf)

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': oauth_conf['client_id'],
        'client_secret': oauth_conf['client_secret'],
        'audience': oauth_conf['audience'],
    }

    response = requests.post(
        oauth_conf['url'],
        json=payload,
        headers=headers
    )
    return response

def another_method():
    return 1+2
```

**contents of `test_keep_alive.py`**

```py
class TestKeepAlive(TestBase, FixturesMixin):
    @mock.patch('src.celery.utils.get_auth_token', return_value='')
    def test_select_1_query(self, connection_mock):
        KeepAlive().run()
        #Do whatever after
```

**contents of `keep_alive.py`**

```py
class KeepAlive(Command):
    
    def run(self):
        auth_token = get_auth_token()
        logging.info("KEEP ALIVE SUCCESS!
```

Now when I run pytest,

```
python -m pytest -v tests/scripts/test_keep_alive.py  -s
```

It is still printing out 'getting auth token' even after I mocked it out. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to mock the import and not the actual function.

The proper path should be

```
@mock.patch('scripts.keep_alive.get_auth_token', return_value='')
```

or something along those lines but you'll need to experiment a bit.